# Saving and listing Category model

Tags: javascript, error-handling, mongodb, express.js

I have this ExpressJS route for saving and listing `Category` model.

```
exports.save = function(req, res, next){
  //validate here>>>
  var name = req.body.name;
  var description = req.body.description;

  new Category({
    name: name,
    description: description,
  }).save(function(err, docs){
    if ( err ) {
      console.log('error: saving category');
      next(error);
    }else{
      console.log('category saved.');
      res.redirect('categories');
    }
  });
}


exports.list = function(req, res, next){
  Category.find(function ( err, categories, count ){
    if (err) {
      console.log('error: listing categories');
      next(error);
    }
    res.render( 'categories/list', {
        categories : categories
    });
  }); 
}
```

Is having `console.log` and `next(error)` OK?  How could I improve the above code in terms of conventions in NodeJS / ExpressJS?

Comment: Instead of the [`console.log`](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_error_data) you could use `console.error` to print errors. It's the same as `console.log` but it prints to stderr. I bet you've seen [this](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) in the documentation of express.js.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a typo there, `error` is nowhere defined but you do have `err`.

To jackdbernier's point, you should read the docs:
http://expressjs.com/guide.html#users-online

In there it is clear that you should call `next` regardless whether you have an error or not, otherwise not all middlewares will be processed.

If you insist on logging before call next, you could.

```
function handleError( message , err , next )
{
  console.error( message );
  return next( err );
}

new Category({
  name: name,
  description: description,
}).save(function(err, docs){
  if ( err ){
    return handleError( 'error: saving category' , err, next );
  } 
  console.log('category saved.');
  res.redirect('categories');
  next(); // <- this!
});
}
```

Though I would personally drop the curly braces from that `if( err )`.